# Why is it stated arbiters don't feel human emotions?

Tags: death-parade

Decim shows empathy. Ginty is angry with the choice the fangirl he judges makes. The rest of the arbiters show human emotions, too. So why does a rule say they don't have human emotions because they're dummies?

Comment: They're not dummies though. If I'm not mistaken, they're something like angels/demons but for the neutral limbo realm. They can't control their emotions 100% and do selfish things sometimes, keep secrets from each other, form alliances, etc. So that rule is there to govern their work of sorting dead people out, but it doesn't mean it can't be broken.

Comment: If it is simply a rule why isnt it enforced? It seemed to me everybody was shocked Decim would be able to hve human emotions

Comment: Who's gonna enforce it? The old guy? It looks like there's no real enforcement there. I'm not sure I remember them discussing a mechanism for firing the "bad employees".

Comment: Thats a good one